# If f32 is not Eq, why does this compile?

Tags: rust, floating-point, traits, equality

I have a generic type such as

```
impl<T: Eq> Eq for Complex<T> where T: Eq {}
```

For some reason, I'm able to make a `Complex<f32>` and have it compile and call `eq()` even though `f32` does not (cannot) support full comparison (because nan!=nan).

How is this possible?

Answer (score 7):

The `eq` method (which is called when you use the `==` operator) is part of the [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) trait, not [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html).

The `Eq` trait inherits all of its methods from `PartialEq`, adding none of its own, and its sole purpose is as a marker to assert that the `==` operator forms an [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) on the implementing type.

Types like `HashMap` rely on `Eq` rather than `PartialEq`, so they can make logical guarantees - for example:

- it must be possible to retrieve a value with the same key as it was inserted with
- if there is a hash collision, the implementation can still distinguish distinct keys using `==`, so one doesn't replace the other.

It is always safe to derive an implementation of `Eq` because it will only be valid if all child fields are also `Eq`. However, if you implement `Eq` yourself, you need to make sure that the equivalence relation invariants are upheld.